# Binary Calculator using Picaxe microchip?

Tags: binary, calculator, picaxe

I want to be a complete nerd and make a very simple binary calculator.

It will be two rows of 8 switches, each switch representing a bit, so a row is a byte (number), the two rows are added together, and a row of 9 LED's will display the result in binary.

Is this possible to do with a picaxe microchip?

If not, what could I do it with?

Cheers,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem would be data input/output lines.  The basic idea is trivial in any microcontroller, but it's the number of input/output pins available.

You might want to look into several [shift registers](http://www.sparkfun.com/search/results?term=shift+register&what=products) (one per row and one per output) so you can marshal the bits in on a single pin or two and out on a single pin.

Specifically:

- [74hc165n parallel-in/serial-out](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9519) for the inputs
- [74hc595](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/733) for the output.